# How to combine two lists after parsing a url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am very new with python. I have a csv with 60 rows with the following format

```
Sku;url
```

I separate them to a url list, I parse the urls and print the results to an output csv. I use multiproccessing and a pool.

But I want to place in front of my results the corresponding SKU of the url

How can I do this?

Comment: Please add more details showing mock data and what your code looks like, eg. your attempt's at solving the issue. [How To Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide details, only thing I can suggest is to keep sku and url together.

Very roughly,

```
def parse_url_and_save_with_sku(url, sku):
    # code that you did not share here
    # does samething except, it utilizes sku to save with corresponding result

lines = list(open("data.csv"))
data_dict = {}
for line in lines:
    separated = line.split(";")
    sku = separated[0]
    url = separated[1]
    parse_url_and_save_with_sku(url, sku)
```

Hope it helps